# using bool method with "?" operator

Tags: c#

I'm trying to minimize my code for learning purpose.

```
void CheckIstrue()
{
    IsTrue() ? Console.WriteLine("True") : Console.WriteLine("False");
}

bool IsTrue()
{
    //do something
    return true; 
}
```

> Error: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because
> there is no implicit conversion between 'system.Action' and 'void'
> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object
> expressions can be used as a statement

How can I fix it? or instead of minimizing these line of code should I use it with an `if` condition?

Comment: You have to use an `if` statement. The `bool ? x : y` is an expression, and an expression is not a valid statement in C#. For example `1+2;` is invalid in C#.

Comment: Use an if statement. Ternary operators are used for _returning_ data based on the branch taken. Ternary (subjectively) make code harder to read.

Comment: Replace the entire `CheckIsTrue` with `Console.WriteLine(IsTrue())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` operator is for computing a value, not executing an action.

A more typical use would be something like this:

```
void CheckIstrue() {
    var output = IsTrue() ? "True" : "False";
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```